# Error in passing string variable in arduino uno in Watterott MI0283QT-2lcd display

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, lcd

I am trying to use Watterott MI0283QT-2 display with arduino uno. When I pass value to lcdDisplay. The below code is working fine and displaying "Hello World"

```
lcd.fillScreen(RGB(255,255,255)); 
lcd.drawTextPGM(5, 2, PSTR("Hello World"), RGB(255,255,255), RGB(0,0,0), 1);
```

But with dynamic String variable, it is giving an error

```
String opt = "Hello World";
lcd.fillScreen(RGB(255,255,255)); 
lcd.drawTextPGM(5, 2, PSTR(opt), RGB(255,255,255), RGB(0,0,0), 1);
```

The error details are given below

> error: initializer fails to determine size of '__c'
>
> lcd.drawTextPGM(5, 2, PSTR(opt), RGB(255,255,255), RGB(0,0,0), 1);
>
> ^
>
> /tmp/034671196/sketch_apr29a/sketch_apr29a.ino:352:33: error: array
>   must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
>
> exit status 1

Comment: `PSTR()` is utterly meaningless with a dynamic string.  Presumably you also have a `lcd.drawText()` function available, which works with strings in RAM instead of program memory.

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. Just one more thing, from where can I get these API resources and their good documentation. I just found the examples on the internet, not good documentation.